# Retrieving Serialized Values

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps-api-3, javascriptserializer

I am using JavaScript serializer to send value to JavaScript:

```
JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        var Result = (from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
                      select new
                      {
                          Latitude = c.Field<Decimal>("Latitude"),
                          Longitude = c.Field<Decimal>("Longitude")
                      }).ToList();

        hdnControl.Value = oSerializer.Serialize(Result);
```

This results in this kind of value:

```
   [
    {"Latitude":19.2094000000,"Longitude":73.0939000000},
    {"Latitude":19.2244070000,"Longitude":73.1545760000},
    {"Latitude":32.5838493257,"Longitude":132.3632812500},
    {"Latitude":59.3331894266,"Longitude":8.6572265625}
   ]
```

How can I retrieve these values in a JavaScript function?
Are there any inbuilt method to access it 
or do I need to use the `.split()` function to get the values?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is javascript json array. You can use `forEach` to retrieve the value using the keys

```
a.forEach(function(item){
document.write('<pre> Latitute is '+item.Latitude+'</pre>')
})
```

A complete list of of array methods is available [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) which can be used as required

[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/ya2ecffr/)

Comment: thnx a lot , this is exactly what i needed.